# Batch variable creation in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

So im writing my first lines of code in Swift, and i want to make a game where you need to tilt the device to make a gravity shift and by doing so make a ball drop to the floor while maneuvering around obstacles.

Ive been looking up different methods, and I found one where you can make the obstacles by just using `let`, For example (Im using UIKit)

`let barrier1 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 300, width: 20, height: 20))
 barrier1.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
view.addSubview(barrier1)`

Its quite a bit of code to declare every barrier this way, and I was hoping if there was a way of doing this in a `while` loop where every time the loop runs, `x = x + 1` is stated and you make variables that way in batch. Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what arrays are for.  Declare a variable called `barriers` of type `[UIView]` and then append each new barrier to this array.

```
var barriers:[UIView] = []

for i in 1...20 {
    let newbarrier = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 300 + i * 30, width: 20, height: 20))
    newbarrier.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    view.addSubview(newbarrier)
    barriers.append(newbarrier)
}

// Now you can refer to each barrier by its index: barriers[0], barriers[1]
// up to barriers[19]
```